# Get general list of photos using flickr API

Tags: api, oauth, flickr

I want to show my customer's flickr page using API.But i don't know which method is used to take the photos which are shown in our home page of flickr.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this API function: https://secure.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.getPhotos.html

(Note that probably you could also call
https://secure.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html
setting the parameter `user_id (Optional)` to the id of your customer's flickr page.)

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is by using Temboo - a service that makes it easy to work with lots of APIs in the programming language of your choice.

Temboo has a method called [ListPublicPhotos](https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Flickr/Photos/ListPublicPhotos/) that is built on top of the Flickr API. You pass it a Flickr API key and the ID of your customer, and it'll return their public photos in JSON format.

You can experiment with this method in your browser and then automatically generate the source code you need to call this behavior from your code.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo, so let me know if you have any questions!)